# How to pass formarray to other component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I want to pass formarray to child component to display formarray values there. Below is the code, what I've tried so far. I am not able to find the way to display the formarray values in the child component.

**app.component.html**

```
<div [formGroup]="userForm">
  <div formArrayName="users">
    <div *ngFor="let user of users.controls; let i = index">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Room Name" [formControlName]="i">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button (click)="addUser()">Add Room</button>
<title [users]="users"></title>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
userForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

public get users(): any {
  return this.userForm.get('users') as FormArray;
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.userForm = this.fb.group({
    users: this.fb.array([this.fb.control('')])
  });
}

addUser() {
  this.users.push(this.fb.control(''));
}
```

**title.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users.controls">{{ user.value }}</div>
```

**title.component.ts**

```
@Input() users;

ngOnChanges(changes) {
  console.log(changes);
}
```

But above code not displaying the formarray values in the child component.

Example stackblitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ajbym9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`title`** is a keyword and its already defined tag with HTML. just use some different name for the component **`selector`**

```
 selector: 'title1',
```

**[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zff1am?file=src/app/title/title.component.ts)**

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. It is working fine now. I can accept  your answer after 10 mins :-)